# Kubernetes replication controller / container regenerate

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Is it currently possible to "repave" or regenerate pods or containers from a replication controller in Kubernetes based on time or condition for security reasons? Would like to recreate container based on schedule every x min/hours or due to condition(like tripwire). I know this could be done externally, just curious if it was an existing feature or if there was clever way to accomplish this objective.

Answer (score 0):

Not something that is directly built in Kubernetes as is, but you could work around that by leveraging a [Liveness probe](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#liveness-and-readiness-probes-aka-health-checks). If any container inside your Pod is scheduled to "fail" on a certain condition (time or event based) Kubernetes will automatically restart the pod, i.e. recreate the failed containers.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [Brendan Burn's ksql script](https://github.com/brendandburns/ksql) to locate target pods. I use this at my company in our deployment CI jobs. SQL searches for all pods that are running an image that I've just rebuilt, passing the results into a BASH `while` loop in which I destroy the affected pods one by one.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build the ksql query
QUERY="SELECT pods.metadata->name, pods.metadata->namespace "
QUERY="${QUERY} FROM pods LEFT JOIN containers USING uid "
QUERY="${QUERY} WHERE image LIKE '%/${CONTAINER_NAME}:${CONTAINER_TAG}'"

exec 5>&1  # Duplicate stdout on #5 so we can display the 
           # results of the query and use them at the same time

# Delete every pod matching QUERY. The `sed` and `awk` calls break down the formatted table
while read line; do
  namespace=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f4`
  pod=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2`
  kubectl delete --namespace=$namespace pod $pod
done < <(echo "$QUERY" | node node_modules/ksql/ksql.js | tee >(cat - >&5) | sed -n 'p;n' | tail -n +3)
```

It's certainly not the most elegant solution in the world, but it could be simple enough to embed this logic in a container running in your cluster.

The upside of this technique is that it's *extremely* flexible and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Does `pod.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` do what you want?  http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_podspec